# Can I compile and execute C++ project without copying any license?

Tags: c++, bash, github

Can I just download and execute a C++ project on GitHub licensed under the MIT license without copying that license somewhere? For example, download a single file, `g++` it and run? What about bash scripts in this repo? There are considered source code, not binary. Can I also execute them without any attribution?

Comment: This should be asked on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ or https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Most open source licences are about redistribution, if you aren't giving code/executables to anybody else you don't need to worry about licences. There are some exceptions like "non-commercial use" licences and licences like AGPL that apply when people are interacting with a program even if they haven't been given a copy

Comment: My gut feeling says it's legal, the restriction should only apply to distributing the code to others. Receiving the code without a license attached is viewed as a bad thing, and the license tries to prevent you from doing this to others. Nobody should care if you do this to yourself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "*Legal questions*, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. [Open Source Stack Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) or [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) may be suitable alternatives." -- see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @JaMiT Perhaps it should be moved to Open Source SE rather than closed?

Comment: @Keiji Don't know. I am not familiar with that site's guidelines for acceptable questions, and I am not motivated to research that. I'd rather close as off-topic than move the question and risk it being closed at the new location. If others know this question is good in its current form for the other site, they can put a migration in motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The MIT license says no

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

That categorically says *all copies*. It doesn't matter if you're the only person with access to a copy.

## But in practice?

When you execute a file, your computer copies its contents (or, at least, "substantial portions" of its contents) into RAM. It doesn't copy the license file into RAM - it doesn't even know about the license file.

I'd argue that if all you're doing is copying a `.c` file that happens to be MIT-licensed off of GitHub, and compiling and executing it to see what it does, you're fine - especially if you know you're going to delete it immediately afterwards.

Where you'd get into trouble is if you set up something using that executable (or source file) sans license, and then later you forget about how that file got there and send it to someone, even privately, for example as a way to share a solution to something, or someone else comes across it by any other means (e.g. if it's on a shared server).

In any case, the safest thing to do would be to just clone the Git repo and run it from there.

Comment: «The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.» — what if there is a copyright header or license comment header in the downloaded file? Does it count as if I copied the license?

Comment: If the entire license text is included in the source file (definitely possible with one as short as MIT), then copying the file is clearly fine as it's copying the license too. If there's just a comment saying "this file is licensed under MIT, see https://mit-license.org/" or the like, that might work fine to remind _you_, but it's unacceptable to distribute, because the person receiving the source file needs access to the license without having to access any external online resource.

Comment: @cppbest The license must be available to the end user. If you are the end user, you have access to the source code, so you don't have to do anything. If you distribute the compiled program to others, you must distribute the license in a text file, unless the text is shown in the program itself.